# How to sperated character from Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I use the example below :

```
select '10+20+30'
```

and generate value :

```
'++'
```

> In other words, strip any digit and leave only signs.

Comment: What do you  mean by this? Please describe your problem clearly

Comment: dang this seems to generate `10+20+30`

Comment: I want to separate the like select '10 + 20 + 30' and becomes '++',

Comment: You want a string to come out for operators? Like '10-9+8-3' is `-+-` ?

Comment: yes sir, that is what I mean

Comment: In other words, strip any digit and leave only signs, right?

Comment: yes sir just signs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Function:**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getMOps;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getMOps
(   s varchar(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE sOut VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE theLen,iLooper INT;
    SET iLooper=1;
    SET theLen=LENGTH(s);
    SET sOut='';
    WHILE iLooper<theLen DO
        IF SUBSTR(s,iLooper,1) IN ('+','-','*','/','^') THEN
            SET sOut=CONCAT(sOut,SUBSTR(s,iLooper,1));
        END IF;
        SET iLooper=iLooper+1;
    END WHILE;
    return (sOut);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
select getMOps('fish'); -- blank string
select getMOps('1+2+7-1'); -- '++-'
```

Modify the `IN` clause to suit your tastes. I am sure there are better ways.

Comment: if using select , whether it could be without the use of function?